# Jquery li selector

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've got this code and I need to get work this script:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.toggle').hide();
  $('li.togglelink').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var elem = $(this).next('.toggle')
    $('.toggle').not(elem).hide();
    elem.toggle();

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="main" class="horizontal">
  <li class="togglelink">Lorem ipsum
    <ul id="drop" class="toggle vertical">
      <li>První</li>
      <li>Druhý</li>
      <li>První</li>
      <li>Druhý</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

How can I make selector for li.togglelink? Why my script doesn't work?

Another important thing: How to hide toggle if isn't togglelink or toggle hovered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use `.find()` instead of `.next()` because you're looking for a class inside of `.togglelink`. And you don't need to use `e.peventDefault()` (unless you plan on adding in links). You can cut down your script too:

```
$('.toggle').hide();
  $('li.togglelink').on('click', function (e) {
  var elem = $(this).find('.toggle').slideToggle();
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.toggle').hide();
  $('li.togglelink').on('click', function(e) {
    var elem = $(this).find('.toggle').slideToggle();

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="main" class="horizontal">
  <li class="togglelink">Lorem ipsum
    <ul id="drop" class="toggle vertical">
      <li>První</li>
      <li>Druhý</li>
      <li>První</li>
      <li>Druhý</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

You could also set `.toggle` to `display: none` in your CSS instead of calling `$('.toggle').hide();` on page load:

```js
$('li.togglelink').on('click', function(e) {
  $(this).find('.toggle').slideToggle();
});
```

```css
.toggle {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="main" class="horizontal">
  <li class="togglelink">Lorem ipsum
    <ul id="drop" class="toggle vertical">
      <li>První</li>
      <li>Druhý</li>
      <li>První</li>
      <li>Druhý</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for help, how to hide toggle if isnt toggle or togglelink hovered?

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with your markup, normally you would use a link inside the `<li>` element or you will have to customize the cursor via CSS. This is how I would do it:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.toggle').hide();

  $('#togglelink > a').click(function(e) {
    $(this).parent().find('.toggle').slideToggle();
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="main" class="horizontal">
  <li id="togglelink">
    <a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>
    <ul id="drop" class="toggle vertical">
      <li>První</li>
      <li>Druhý</li>
      <li>První</li>
      <li>Druhý</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because `.next()` selects 'siblings', and you're trying to select a 'child', for which you'd need `children()`, or more generally `.find()`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.toggle').hide();
  $('li.togglelink').on('click', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var elem = $(this).find('.toggle')
      $('.toggle').children().not(elem).hide();
      elem.toggle();

  });
});
```

In this case, it'll toggle all children of `.togglelink`, except for the `<ul>` elements that have class `toggle`. I'm not sure if that's the desired result, but at least doing something with `.find()` instead of `.next()` probably fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.toggle').hide();
$('.togglelink').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var elem = $(this).find('.toggle')
    $('.toggle').not(elem).hide();
    elem.toggle();

});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
How can I make selector for li.togglelink? Why my script not works?

    <ul id="main" class="horizontal">
<li class="togglelink">Lorem ipsum
<ul id="drop" class="toggle vertical">
<li>První</li>
<li>Druhý</li>
<li>První</li>
<li>Druhý</li>
</ul>
</li>

</li>
</ul>
```